# Redux-actions Jest testing

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, redux, jestjs

I use 'redux-actions' and have async action creator in Redux
I try to write unit tests, but get an error:

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 100000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

Probably this is due to the call of the timer inside my action.
How can I fix this error?

`actions.js`

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { createAction } from 'redux-actions';

export const loadingNewsRequest = createAction('LOADING_NEWS_REQUEST');
export const loadingNewsSuccess = createAction('LOADING_NEWS_SUCCESS');
export const loadingNewsFailure = createAction('LOADING_NEWS_FAILURE');

const path = 'http://127.0.0.1:7000';
const timeout = 5000;
const loadingTimeout = 60000;

export const loadNews = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(loadingNewsRequest());
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${path}/news`, { timeout });
    const timer = setTimeout(() => loadNews()(dispatch), loadingTimeout);
    dispatch(loadingNewsSuccess({ allNews: response.data, timer }));
  } catch (err) {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => loadNews()(dispatch), loadingTimeout);
    dispatch(loadingNewsFailure({ err: err.message, timer }));
  }
};
```

`actions.test.js`

```
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as actions from './index';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);

describe('loadNews', () => {
  const newsData = [ { x: 1}, { y: 2} ];

  it('returns data when sendMessage is called', async (done) => {
    const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
    mock.onGet('http://127.0.0.1:7000/news').reply(200, newsData);

    jest.setTimeout(100000);

    const expectedActions = [
      actions.loadingNewsRequest(),
      actions.loadingNewsSuccess(
        {
          allNews: newsData,
          timer: 4,
        },
      ),
    ];
    const initialState = { allNews: [], timer: null };
    const store = mockStore(initialState);

    await store.dispatch(actions.loadNews());
    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async` function returns a promise that is consumed by Jest. `done` callback is a legacy way to write asynchronous tests. It should never be used simultaneously with promises and `async` functions.

`done` takes priority over a promise in a way Jest handles asynchronous tests. Since `done` is never called, it waits for a timeout and fails.

It should be:

```
  it('returns data when sendMessage is called', async () => {
  ...
```

100000 is too much for a timeout, if there is asynchronous process, it completes complete within several seconds. 15000 is long enough to make sure a test never completes.